# Careers certifications "Time frame"

Tags: discussion, jobs, timestamps, cv

The "Time frame" drop downs on the Careers site -> CV -> Certifications seems ambiguous to me. Should people specify it as (currently) years studied for certification, or just years valid.

Subsequent point if the later - The latest year available to select in both from and to is (currently) 2013, which leads me to the assumption that it is years currently studied for.

I see three aspects:

```
 A) Deciding on one or two sets of drop-downs (For one or both timeframes)
 B) Clearly specifying what one (or, obviously two for both) of the ranges is for
 C) Fixing up the date range to include a decent number of years in the future
    should a valid range be defined / added.
```

Thoughts?